# ember.js `afterModel` event handler changes not reflected in Template

Tags: ajax, ember.js, promise

I have a route in which I use Ajax (not Ember Data) to pull a record, a `costcentre`, off the server. The record is intended to populate a template for subsequent edits.

Before the fetch, in `beforeModel`, an empty `costcentre` is created using `createRecord`. After the `model` processing is complete, in `afterModel`, the returned data is used to populate the `costcentre` object in the Data Store.

The fetch of the data is successful and in the debugger the update of the locally stored DS object can be seen to have worked but the changes are not seen in the template.

How can I get the template to populate with the data returned from the server ?

In the route I have this :

```
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    this.set('ccToEdit', this.store.createRecord('costcentre'));
  },

  model(params) {
      return getCCByCCIdent(    this.urlbase,
                                this.currentMOP.currentMOP,
                                ENV.APP.MATClientCode,
                                params.cceIdentifier_to_edit);
  },
  afterModel(ccs, transition) {
    //I'm testing this with an API end point that returns a
    //list but there will only ever be one item in the list

    this.ccToEdit.setProperties(ccs[0]);
  },
```

The `getCCByCCIdent` looks like this :

```
export const getCCByCCIdent = function(urlbase, currentMOP, clientCode, targetCostCentreIdent) {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (targetCostCentreIdent.length == 0)
    {
      resolve([])
    }
    else
    {
      var theUrl = `${urlbase}/costcentres/${currentMOP}/${clientCode}/${targetCostCentreIdent}`;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: theUrl,
        success: function (response) {
          resolve(response);
          },
        error: function (request, textStatus, error) {
          reject(error);
          }
        });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: how do you use `ccToEdit` in the template?

Comment: Without afterModel you can do same, you want the use the variable which depends on the endpoint response, IMO wait for the response assign it to some variable and then use it in a template by returning the custom object in `model()` which will have the response and `ccToEdit` both

Comment: @VaibhavRai - sorry for the slow response. What you describe is more or less what I ended up doing. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to do a `then()` on the promise being returned from your Ajax call, set appropriate values after that and then return your model:

```
model(params) {
  return getCCByCCIdent(
    this.urlbase,
    this.currentMOP.currentMOP,
    ENV.
    params.cceIdentifier_to_edit
  ).then(ccs => {
    let costCentre = this.store.createRecord('costcentre');
    costCentre.setProperties(ccs[0]);
    return costCentre;
  });
},
```

Comment: sorry not to have responded before. This is more or less what I ended up doing and it worked. I do the 'createRecord' in the 'beforeModel' but that's just because that's how I first tried it and it worked that way, I'm sure your version would work as well. The key to it, as you point out, is the the 'setProperties' being in the 'then'.